# Finding total number of characters in array after reducing

Tags: javascript, arrays

How would I find the total number of characters (including spacing and commas) in the array after using `.reduce`?

Ex.
Say I had an array, that when using `.reduce((prev, curr) => [prev, ', ', curr])`, would result in

```
array: item1, item2, item3
```

And when I find the amount of characters, it would be 19 (without 'array: ').

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you do `join` method instead of `reduce`. For your case,

```
let array = ['item1', 'item2', ' item3 '];
const strLength = array.join().length;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one with `.reduce()`

```js
const strLength = ["item1", "item2", "item3"].reduce((prev, curr) => `${prev}, ${curr}`).length
```

Comment: :) looks like exactly what OP asked. Just barfs on an empty array.

Comment: Yep, I just made an assumption that there will always be items in the array

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
var sumCharLengths = ['alpha ',' beta ','gamma'].reduce((a, b) => a + b.length, 0);
```

- `a` is your "accumulator" value
- `b` is the current array item as the reducer "loops" over the array
- `0` is the start value for your accumulator

More documentation here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Alternatively, without `reduce()`, you could just `join()` the array items and take the length of that result, e.g.:

```
var sumCharLengths = ['alpha ',' beta ','gamma'].join().length
```

Comment: When I use join(), it returns [Object object], [Object object] for me

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question. Are you sure your array is an array of strings as you described in you problem statement?  Maybe you could be more explicit with your example. Because if you copy and paste exactly what's captured above into a web console, you'll see that it calculates correctly into the `sumCharLengths` variable.

Comment: Yes, it does have a list of strings

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand the question correctly if that you want the sum of the lenghts of an array of strings?

```js
// I would define the function sum as
const sum = (iterable, start = 0) => iterable.reduce((a, b) => a + b, start);
// then
let array = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
// and we can sum their lengths like this
console.log(sum(array.map((s) => s.length)));
// but then we're off because you want a comma and a space between them all
// so we should start with 2 * (length of array - 1)
console.log(sum(array.map((s) => s.length), 2 * (array.length - 1)));
// iff we have a items at all ofcourse
array = [];
console.log(sum(array.map((s) => s.length),
  array.length ? 2 * (array.length - 1) : 0));
```

But really, the `join().length` solution others mentioned is cleverer.